# Parse CData from XML in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, cdata

Am trying to parse my xml which has CData tag as the value for one of its nodes. My XML structure is as below.

```
<node1>
<node2>
<![CDATA[ <!--@@@BREAK TYPE="TABLE" @@@--> <P><CENTER>... html goes here.. ]]>
</node2>
</node1>
```

My code is as below. When I parse I get response with CData tag and not the value in the CData tag. Can you pls help me fix my problem?

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
XElement node1Element = xmlDoc.Descendants("node1").FirstOrDefault();
string cdataValue = node1Element.Element("node2").Value;

Actual Output: <![CDATA[ <!--@@@BREAK TYPE="TABLE" @@@--> <P><CENTER>... html goes here.. ]]>

Expected Output:  <!--@@@BREAK TYPE="TABLE" @@@--> <P><CENTER>... html goes here..
```

I was not sure if System.XML.Linq.XDocument was causing the problem. So I tried XMLDocument version as below.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(@"/node1/node2");
XmlNode childNode = node.ChildNodes[0];
if (childNode is XmlCDataSection)
{}
```

And my if loop returns false. So looks like there is something wrong with my xml and it is actually not a valid CData? Pls help me fix  the problem.
Pls let me know if  you need more details.

Comment: Is there a reason why this question was downvoted? I have tried to make sure I provide all necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because StreamReader was escaping the html. So "<" was getting changed to `"&lt;"`. Hence it was not getting recognized correctly as a cdatatag. So had to do unescape first - 
`XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseString))`

and that fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing will never actually happen. Getting the `Value` of a node that contains `cdata` as a child will give you the contents of the `cdata`, the inner text.  You should already be getting your expected output.

The only way you can get the actual cdata node is if you actually get the `cdata` node.

```
var cdata = node1Element.Element("node2").FirstNode;
```

Comment: But this is the output am getting and am not sure  if am missing something obvious. Hence I wanted to check with peers here. I know I am supposed to get the contents of cdata, but am not.

Comment: First, try to reproduce the problem without getting your data from some response. Create a string with the contents of that response and run that string through the code in a separate program.  You will not get what you say you're getting.  If you do somehow, then that means your input string is _not_ what you had posted here.  Post that string if it does match what you say.

Comment: Standalone console program with string works perfectly fine, and produces result as expected - just the text inside the cdata tag. But when I run my actual code with response from server, it does not work fine.

Comment: You should post that response from the server exactly as it is here then.  Maybe rename some nodes to anonymize it a bit.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was because StreamReader was escaping the html. So "<" was getting changed to "&lt;". So had to do unescape first - XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseString)) and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and the CData value are correct... ?!?

how you fill your reponseString? :-)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string responseString = "<node1>" +
                          "<node2>" +
                          "<![CDATA[ <!--@@@BREAK TYPE=\"TABLE\" @@@--> <P><CENTER>... html goes here.. ]]>" +
                          "</node2>" +
                          "</node1>";

  XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(responseString);
  XElement node1Element = xmlDoc.Descendants("node1").FirstOrDefault();
  string cdataValue = node1Element.Element("node2").Value;

  // output:  <!--@@@BREAK TYPE=\"TABLE\" @@@--> <P><CENTER>... html goes here.. 
}
```

Comment: @MarxKlaxx, It was because StreamReader was escaping the html. So "<" was getting changed to "&lt;". So had to do unescape first - XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseString)) and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this case in this form:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(vm.Xml);

XNamespace cbc = @"urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2";
  var list2 =
       (from el in xdoc.Descendants(cbc + "Description")
        select el).FirstOrDefault();

      var queryCDATAXML = (from eel in list2.DescendantNodes()                                                
      select eel.Parent.Value.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();
```